# The fate of a Mujahir

Tags: sin, tawba

I need help concerning the fate of a person who exposes his sins whether out of pride or neglect. In an authentic hadith it is said that such a person will not be forgiven. Is this absolute? Can a mujahir still repent before he or she dies as he reaffirm his Iman? Or is it futile meaning there is no hope for such a person despite having Iman?

Answer (score 0):

Is a sin to expose your bad deeds, when a man at night sins and in the morning while Allah hid his sins he goes and tells people I did so and so. This was similiarily narrated in a hadith. And they shall not be forgiven unless that individual repents sincerely and promises never to expose sins whether done for education purpose or not.

“Say: “O ‘Ibaadi (My slaves) who have transgressed against themselves (by committing evil deeds and sins)! Despair not of the Mercy of Allaah, verily, Allaah forgives all sins. Truly, He is Oft-Forgiving, Most Merciful” [al-Zumar 39:53].

So what you must do is ignore shaytan as he's putting thoughts into you making you believe Allah won't forgive when the Almighty will certainly forgive you if you turn back to him with sincerity. He is more Merciful than a mother is to her child  even if your bad deeds was as high as a mountain he will still forgive so long as death don't approach you and the sun does not rise from the west.